# My code works fine inside the python shell, but not showing anything when running it on my Visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The code works inside Python shell, but not inside VS Code terminal. 
    Can anyone please help me, I am about to go nuts.

```
I have tested my code on several ide and it works fine, just on VS 

board = ["  " for i in range(9)]


def print_board():
    row1 = "| {} | {} | {} |".format(board[0], board[1], board[2])
    row2 = "| {} | {} | {} |".format(board[3], board[4], board[5])
    row3 = "| {} | {} | {} |".format(board[6], board[7], board[8])

    print(row1)
    print(row2)
    print(row3)
    print()


def player_move(icon):

    if icon == "X":
        number = 1
    elif icon == "O":
        number = 2

    print("Your turn player {}".format(number))

    choice = int(input("Enter your move (1-9): ").strip())
    if board[choice - 1] == "  ":
        board[choice - 1] = icon
    else:
        print()
        print("That space is taken!")
```

I need to see the board that I have created, it simply does not show anything inside VS code

It simply does not show anything inside the terminal and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0):

while you define your print statements in `print_board()` you never actually call it.

Just add

```
print_board()
```

to the end and wherever appropriate.

---

so your code might look something like:

```
import numpy as np

board = [" " for i in range(9)]
icons = {1:"X", 2:"O"}

def print_board(remove=0):
    if remove > 0:
        print('\x1b[1A\x1b[2K'*remove)
    boardString = "| {} | {} | {} |\n"*3
    print(boardString.format(*board))


def player_move(_turn):
    player = np.mod(_turn,2)+1
    print("Your turn player {}".format(player))

    while True:
        choice = int(input("Enter your move (1-9): "))
        if board[choice - 1] == " ":
            board[choice - 1] = icons[player]
            break
        else:
            print('\x1b[1A\x1b[2K'*3)
            print("That space is taken!")

    print_board(7)

print_board()
for turn in range(9):
    player_move(turn)
```

```
| X | O | X |
| O |   |   |
|   |   |   |

Your turn player 1
Enter your move (1-9):
```

some notes:

- As shown above, you can replaces the last print of the board and command prompt by utilising [VT100 codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor) for going up a line (`\x1b[1A`) and removing a line (`\x1b[2K`) before printing anew
- strings can be multiplied (repeated) like lists

```
In [1]: print('a'*3)                                                                      
> aaa
```

- you can add `\n` for a line break to strings instead of calling `print()` multiple times

```
In [25]: print('a\nb')                                                              
> a
> b
```

- you can unpack iterable variables (lists, tuples..) by using `*` or `**`

```py
yourDict = {'a':3, 'b':4}
yourList = [1, 2]

yourFun(*yourList, **yourDict )
# is equvivalent to:
yourFun(1, 2, a=3, b=4 )
```